# Home-made format and Flashmode

Tags: xetex, texshop, automation

I work with TeXShop 3.51 and OS X 10.9.5 on a MacMini 2012 + SSD.

I successfully compiled a XeLaTeX format, say uo,
and I can use it :

```
   %&uo
   % !TEX TS-program = uo

   \input uo-fonts.tex

   \begin{document}
   L'élégance du hérisson. 
   ${\mathrm e}^{i\pi}=-1$
   \end{document}
```

(I was obliged to extract all references to fonts 
from the format, which explains the `\input uo-fonts.tex`
outside the format.)

But when I try to use this format with Claus Gerhardt's
[Flashmode](http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/gerhardt/Flashmode/), nothing happens.

My system is a french one, 
so I use the Flashmode 7.2.0 special.

Any comments ?  Thank you.

---

Flashmode is a script which makes TeXShop loop indefinitly.
You type something, Flashmode sees it and asks TeXShop
to compile your file, on so on.

Flashmode 7.2.0 special works well on my machine with 
plain, pdflatex, xetex and xelatex formats. I don't know why,
but the script 'quit Flashmode' does not work correctly ;
I have to kill it from the Terminal.

My uo format (uo is a wink for 'University of Oregon', see TeXShop help)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
... \dump
```

contains only very classical macros, without any trouble.

The file uo-fonts.tex (which is outside the format) contains essentially otf fonts definitions :

```
\setmainfont    [Ligatures=TeX]     {TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont    [Scale=1.05]        {TeX Gyre Pagella Math} 
\setmathfont    [range=\mathcal]    {Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont    [range=\ell]        {Latin Modern Math}
```

plus a few exotic fonts, such as

```
\newfontfamily\sectionfont      [Scale=.80]  {Textile}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont   [Scale=.72]  {Textile}
```

This uo format works well under Xelatex.

I compiled it with the Terminal command
xelatex -ini &xelatex uo.tex
The file uo.fmt belongs to ~/Library/texmf/web2. The file
uo.engine belongs to  ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines
and contains the code

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
xelatex  -fmt uo "$1"
```

The trouble is that Flashmode does not work with this format. 
When Flashmode begin, there is a little 'jerk' ; with this uo format,
 no jerk, nothing happens ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is a Flashmode? I don't understand your question at all

Comment: According to the [flashmode homepage](http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/gerhardt/Flashmode/) only `%&pdflatex`, `%&cont-en`, `%&pdftex`, `%&xelatex`, and `%&xetex` are recognized.

Comment: Maybe you have to add the path to `ou.fmt` in `/Applications/Flashmode.app/Contents/Resources/flashmode-ts-xelatex`

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the source file should start with `%&xelatex`
and the shell script

```
/Applications/Flashmode.app/Contents/Resources/flashmode-ts-‌​xelatex
```

should contain the command line

```
xelatex --fmt uo --shell-escape --file-line-error-style --parse-first-line --synctex=1  $1
```

CG

Comment: what is shell script?